# Need help for jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, form-submit

I searched a lot and tried many solutions but no success.

Can you please help me to figure out what mistake I am doing with following jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    var $form = $('#contact_form');

    $form.submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../validateNumber.php",
            data: {"mobile": $('#mobile-number').val()},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response=="invalid"){
                    $(".head").text("Please enter valid mobile number");
                    $( "#mobile-number" ).focus();
                }
            }            
        }); 
    });
    });
    </script>
```

The code is working fine. I am getting error on response == "invalid". But my form is not submitted.

Thanks

Comment: relative path is not supported, I believe. url: "../validateNumber.php"

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Comment: @wannadream the url is working. The only thing is form is not getting submitted. Is there anything I am missing to add?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. No any error. Just the form is not getting submitted

Comment: could you also include your html form?

Comment: form is submitting ,,so you get the response

Comment: If you are still working on it, can you open dev tools in chrome or firefox and have a look at network tab? Open tools before submitting the form and the request will be recorded. Then you can investigate what is happening in request/response tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the handler but never actually submit the form. Is this what you want, submitting form automatically?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $form = $('#contact_form');

    $form.submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "../validateNumber.php",
            data: {"mobile": $('#mobile-number').val()},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response=="invalid"){
                    $(".head").text("Please enter valid mobile number");
                    $( "#mobile-number" ).focus();
                }
            }            
        }); 
    });

    $form.submit();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {  
$('#contact_form').submit( function(e) {
  if( $('#contact_form').valid()){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../validateNumber.php",
        data: {"mobile": $('#mobile-number').val()},
        success: function(response) {
            if(response=="invalid"){
                $(".head").text("Please enter valid mobile number");
                $( "#mobile-number" ).focus();
            }
        }            
    }); }

});
});
</script>
```